# What kind of query language is this?

Tags: sql

I was given a querystring that looks something like the following:

```
"(foo :"bar" OR baz : "qux") AND
 (abc:def OR test:ok OR (fish:carp AND foobar:bazqux))
 AND NOT otherthing:true 
 AND -(-derp:*) 
 OR (name:* AND abcdef:[* TO *])"
```

I need to figure out what query language this is so I can find the rest of the documentation on it, but I can't seem to figure out exactly what it is. It appears to be some form of SQL, but it has some small differences from what I've previously seen. Does anyone know what this might be?

Comment: Very weird syntax, no functions, no operators between quotes and (i assume) variables..are you sure this is the whole picture? maybe a more complete example might help (instead of derp and foobars)

Comment: Where did you get this from? an email? a post to a webpage? Have you sanitised this? It doesn't look real world.

Comment: @pkExec There are no variables in this. The strings without quotes are also being treated as strings. Also, I believe that the querystring I was given only represents the WHERE clause (or some equivalent of it) and not the entire query

Comment: Try SPARQL. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARQL Seems as f***ed up as your example :)

Comment: @pkExec Ah! I think I've found it! It appears to be this: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax

Comment: @Ari my condolences then (I guess you were given something to debug..)